# Incomprehensible default initialization of POD

Tags: c++, initialization, default

I read a lot here and in cppreference that automatic POD types isn't default initializated, but I tried to test some codes and I had some strange results. Look:

```
#include <iostream>

int main( ) {
    int x;
    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It will output *x* some random value. But if I modify my code like this:

```
#include <iostream>

void f( ) { 
    int i;
    std::cout << "i: " << i << std::endl;
}

int main( ) {
    f( );
    int x;
    std::cout << "x: " << x << std::endl;   
    return 0;
}
```

I'll have the following output:

```
i: 0
x: 4200814
```

And if I modify the order of the function call `f( );` for after the declaration of x and its output, both *x* and *i* will set to a random value. Another thing: if I declare another variable with no initialization after the declaration of x and its output, like `int y;`, y will output 0 too.

So, why that variable *i* and possibly all others variables declared in function *f* are 'initializated' to 0. Maybe a consequence of underfined behavior or indeterminate value?

Comment: Yes, this is undefined behavior. Just because you see `0` doesn't mean it was initialized. It just happened to be `0`, no more no less.

Comment: Why are you prejudiced against 0?  It can serve as an uninitialized value just like any other integer.

Comment: Like others have said, Just because a stack variable winds up with 0 doesn't mean it was initialized to zero. It can just as easily be an artifact of how the stack space for the function was created or what the contents were prior to the function stack allocation. One way to check is to look at the assembly code produced. You won't find that the function initlaizes the stack variables. They are what they were. Now if you put them in a container like vector<int> they will be initialized to 0.

Comment: "_One way to check is to look at the assembly code produced._" Thanks for this tip. I just would like to emphasize this because I never think about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I read a lot here and in cppreference that automatic POD types isn't default initializated,

That is not correct. When an object is not explicitly initialized, it is default initialized. What it means to be default initialized changes based on the type.

From C++11 Standard:

> **8.5 Initializers**
>
> ...
>
> 6 To *default-initialize* an object of type `T` means:
>
> — if `T` is a (possibly cv-qualified) class type (Clause 9), the default constructor for `T` is called (and the initialization is ill-formed if `T` has no accessible default constructor);
>
> — if `T` is an array type, each element is default-initialized;
>
> — otherwise, no initialization is performed.

Hence no initialization is performed for `x` and `i`.

---

> Maybe a consequence of underfined behavior or indeterminate value?

Yes. Using the values of uninitialized variables is cause for undefined behavior.

The values of `i` and `x` can be anything. Don't count on any specific pattern.
Their values would most likely change when you recompile, when you change compiler options, change compiler.

Comment: Just a new question about **undefined behavior** which I believe doesn't need an edit of my post: I included an `i++;` after the first print of _i_ and included a new print of _i_ after its increment. In my mind I believed that an access of undefined behavior will cause some problem of my program but _i_ got the value _1_. So, even being a zero "sane" value but indeterminate, can I access this "crazy" value and work with it?

Comment: @FernandoK. you can but you should not. Always initialize your variables before you use them. Why would you want to leave your program in a state that is supposed to invoke undefined behavior?

Comment: @R Sahu _Always initialize your variables before you use them._ I had asked just because I was trying to understand perfectly about default initilization. But now, I'm gonna always initialize them. Thanks.